# How does Nginx's $request_length correspond to byte size?

Tags: nginx

I'm using Nginx and I would like to know the byte size of the data which is returned **to** the client as well as the size received **from** the client.

I'm doing this as following:

- `$bytes_sent` is the [size in bytes](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#var_bytes_sent) which the server is sending **to** the client. This is what I want
- `$request_length` is the *length* of the request **from** the client which includes the [request line, header, and request body](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#var_request_length).

Now my question is this: *How does the **length** of the request map onto the **bytes** received by the server?*

Comment: `$bytes_sent` is the other direction. The only other variable that might help is `$content_length`.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith – I'm not sure I follow. `$bytes_sent` is the number of bytes the server is sending to the client, right? And the `$request_length` is the length of the request the client is sending to the server?

Comment: Yes, `$bytes_sent` is the number of bytes the server is sending to the client. In your question you state that `$bytes_sent` is the size in bytes of the request **from the client** (which is incorrect).

Comment: Gotcha  (updated the question). Do you think I can determine the byte size coming **from** the client based on the `$request_length`?